# HMM package in R crashing

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models, bayesian-networks

I'm using the HMM package to compute BKT group parameter estimates for students learning in R. Right now, my code produces the matrices I want for all all except for the last knowledge component (kc in the code). But then it continues running for a while and eventually rstudio crashes. Right now my code looks like this:

```
require("hmm.discnp")

## load student roll-up
df <- data.frame(read.table(file="C:/Users/Ajay Phatak/Documents/school/Summer 2015/150321GIPathwaysPreprocHCAtt183-31 M2A.txt",na.strings="NA",sep="\t",quote="",header=TRUE, fill=TRUE))

#df_subset <- df[,c(3,7,15,20,21,23)]
df_subset <- df[,c(5,21,27,39,38)]
#change first attempt to accuracy, change kc default to kc(model2a),
df_subset$Accuracy <- as.numeric(as.vector(df_subset$Accuracy))

df_subset <- na.omit(df_subset)

kc_list <- unique(df_subset$KC.Model.2A.)
#loop on the kc_list
for (kc in kc_list)
  {
  print(kc)
  one_kc <- df_subset[ which(df_subset$KC.Model.2A.==kc), ]
  one_kc <- one_kc[,c(1,3)]
  # remove users with few observations on this skill
  by_user = split(one_kc, one_kc$Anon.Student.id)
  obs_by_user = sapply(by_user, nrow)
  valid_users = names(obs_by_user[obs_by_user > 2])
  student_outcomes = one_kc[one_kc$Anon.Student.id %in% valid_users,]

  by_good_user = split(student_outcomes$Accuracy,     student_outcomes$Anon.Student.id)



# attempt to estimate model parameters
  my_hmm = hmm(by_good_user, yval=c(0,1),
               par0=list(tpm=rbind(c(0.8,0.2),c(0.01,0.99)),
                         Rho=rbind(c(0.75,0.25),c(0.25,0.75))),
               stationary=FALSE)
  if (!my_hmm$converged) {
    print(sprintf("Error!  HMM did not converge for skill %s!", kc))
  } else {
    #for (user_id in valid_users) {
      #student_est = sp(correct_by_user[[user_id]], object = my_hmm, means=TRUE)
      #print(sprintf("%s/%s: %f chance know, %f chance correct", skill, user_id,     student_est$probs[2,ncol(student_est$probs)],     student_est$means[length(student_est$means)]))
      # print(correct_by_user[[user_id]])
    #}
  }

# transition probability matrix
print(my_hmm$tpm)
# output probabilities
print(my_hmm$Rho)
# initial probabilities (don't know/know)
print(my_hmm$ispd)
}
```

The data is an excel spreadsheet where each row is a transaction, and the columns are the student id's, the kc that the student answered, and the accuracy, along with some other less important stuff. Any ideas as to why this is crashing?

Comment: How large is this dataset? Are you running out of memory?

Comment: not large enough that I should be running out of memory, I think. only a couple thousand rows in the file